# React setState replacing wrong values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

This is probably a really stupid, facepalm inducing question...

Any reason why when I run this code (from a checkbox) it would replace the "errors" list as well as the "displayErrors" list.  I am keeping my list in two places so I can filter and then bring back the original list.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { date: new Date(), errors: [], displayErrors: [], onlyErrors: false };
}

filterErrors() {
    // I would have placed a dataset in both "errors" and "displayErrors"

    console.log(this.state);

    let err = this.state.errors;
    err.Stock = [];

    this.setState({displayErrors: err });

    console.log(this.state);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because the arrays are objects and when you set err.Stock to be [], it's actually setting this.state.errors to be [] as well. you need to make a copy of your object somehow instead (without knowing what your object is I can't really help with that).

Also you shouldn't be console logging the state after calling setState, setState is asynchronous so the log may or may not print out the new state.

Comment: Thanks, you're right - I should be using the immutability helpers - I forgot it would be using a reference.  From what I remembered of React I'm surprised I was able to change something in state without the setState to begin with!

Comment: Well you're "allowed" to change something in state, but doing it doesn't call forceUpdate (which will do a render) so you end up with something that has a different state then what it's rendering which is why we say not to do it. In your case, you changed the state accidentally, then changed it on purpose, which called forceUpdate, which rerendered everything.

Answer (score 0):

What do you see when you console.log(err.Stock)? Prior to setting it to an empty array of course.I suspect undefined. Dot (".") syntax is used to access attributes of an object(behaviour or state). An array doesn't have attributes as such, it is an ordered set of objects. I suspect you need to iterate over your array and return the Stock object(not sure how to do this without knowing more about the Stock object). Then set the Stock object equal to an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine your current errors using `Object.assign()`:

Example taken from the site:

```
var o1 = { a: 1 };
var o2 = { b: 2 };
var o3 = { c: 3 };

var obj = Object.assign(o1, o2, o3);
console.log(obj); // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
console.log(o1);  // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, target object itself is changed.
```

`Object.assign()` will change the targeted object that you included as parameter, so I think what you need to do is something like `Object.assign({}, error_lists, new_error)` in which you have an empty object  added with your existing and new error object to create a new object.

[Click here for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign%5B1%5D)